# How many chem addictions are in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

There are many chems in Fallout 4 but some are created by mixing existing chems and add only the addiction of one of their components.

What is the maximum number of unique addictions a player character can have?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 'mixed' chems addicts you to their prefix. For example, Buffjet addicts you to Buffout and Psychobuff addicts you to Psycho.

Special chems which does not contain the name of another chem have their own addiction. For example, X-Cell or Overdrive have their own addiction, even if the latter is made with Psycho. By the same rule, Berry Mentats or Ultra Jet addicts you to Mentats and Jet respectively.

You can also get addicted to alcohol (Any type), which is in its own category.

I was able to get addicted to a total of 11 different things.

Here's the effect of all the addictions on a character:

[image: Drugged out]

As you can see, he's suffering a total loss of 26 SPECIAL points and 20 damage resist. Don't do drugs kids.

---

If paired with the Junkie legendary mod, on a simple 110 damage unmodded Gauss Rifle, you can get a nice 265% damage boost:

[image: Junkie Gauss Rifle vs normal]

It seems to stay consistent between different weapon types, a standard 10mm pistol with no upgrades will go from 18 to 47 damage.

Do drugs kids.

Comment: Any idea how much bonus damage you get when using the junkies legendary prefix on a weapon?

Comment: @SkyHiRider About 265% bonus damage, I edited the answer to display an example.

Comment: Is the 265% damage bonus from Junkie you reference scaled to how many addictions you have, or do you get that same 265% bonus even with just 1 addiction effect active? If it's the latter, I might have to reconsider my stance on drug use and find one that doesn't have THAT bad of a withdrawal effect... I'm looking at you, Mentats.

Comment: @king14nyr The description says `Does increasing amounts of damage the more withdrawal effects you suffer`. With only one addiction, it's a small 14.5% damage increase on the Gauss rifle, from 110 to 126 damage. So it does really scale.

Comment: Were any new addictions added in the Season pass?